# Android Manifest missing the package name line?

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest

I was trying to set up firebase, which needed the package name of my current app, except when I went to the android manifest, I did not find the package name line, which shoud be in the second line, is that normal?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="audio_inspect_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    </application>
```

Usually it's :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.myapp">
<application ... >
 ...
</application>
```

Not sure what to do about this?

Answer (score 1):

The package name is in your `gradle` file of your project, not in manifest.

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your **build.gradle** file for **package name**. Here is the gradle file example

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

**Package name** and **applicationId** both are same.

Answer (score 1):

is this a flutter project?. if so you can find it in the android =>app=>src=>build.gradle. Scroll down to the android tag. Namespace should be your package name. yes it's normal I checked mine and got the same result as you.

Answer (score 1):

Not having the `package` attribute in the manifest is not an issue. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element) states,

> *In the Gradle-based build system, starting with AGP 7.3, don't set the package value in the source manifest file directly.*

It can now be found in the gradle file. Once again the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module#set-application-id) states,

> *Your application ID is defined by the applicationId property in your module's build.gradle file, as shown here.*

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```